# InDesign: Applying Stroke to Similar Types of Text Across a Document

Tags: adobe-indesign, stroke, selections, cc-2014

I am using InDesign CC 2014 but this may apply to other versions.

I have text throughout a document that of a particular paragraph style.  I am trying to bold this text.  There are over 350 of these text object so selecting them all one by one, if this was even possible, is not something I am interested in doing.

As the font I am using does not have a bold variant, I am trying to apply a stroke.  I am able to do this for individual text I have selected using Stroke in the toolbar but I want to do this across the entire document either by:

1. Selecting all of this type of text using its paragraph style if possible.
2. Selecting all of this type of text using the layer if possible.
3. By making a change in the Paragraph Style Options.  I do not see an option for this.
4. Something I have not thought of.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Object Styles is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

So (1) all text already has a Paragraph Style applied, and (2) you want all of the text with this style in faux bold?

Text Stroke is an attribute of text in a Paragraph Style. It's (kind of) hidden under Character Color. By default, the proxy is set to change the *fill* color, but you can click it to select *stroke* color. The thickness and some other attributes can be set as well.

It's even more easier to change some text in your document until you like what it looks like, then select "Redefine Paragraph Style" in the style menu pullout menu.

Comment: I was going to give the same answer, but I didn't know about that `Redefine Paragraph Style`, that's great!